# How can I target the specific .data in my html code

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5.3

I had a problem with updating my posts, turns out i'm targetting the wrong node for the Id. Here is my html code where I'm trying to target the Id:

```
<article class="post col-md-6" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}"> <!-- this is what I need to target -->
          <div class="media postforeach postborderleft" >
               <div class="media-left media-top">

               </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <header class="post-title"><h5 class="media-heading">{{ $post->title }}<i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right " aria-hidden="true"></i></h5> </header>
                <p class="post-body"><i>{{ $post->body }}</i></p>
                <div class="info">
                    Posted by {{ $post->user->name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>
              @if (Auth::check())
                <div class="interaction">
                      <a href="#" class="like">Like</a> |
                      <a href="#" class="like">Dislike</a>
                @if (Auth::user() == $post->user)
                        |
                      <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                      <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="like">Delete</a>
                 @endif
                </div>
              @else
                <a href="{{ route('registeration') }}" class="like" style="color: red">Login to interract with posts!</a>
              @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </article>
```

At the top of code You can see the `<article class="post col-md-6" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">` this is where I need to get my Id and the code i'm trying to acces is like this:`postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];` I tried a few more things to acces the Id but the only way I could succeed was deleting most of my html than I could easly access it, but that is not what I wish. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I suspect that the server method is throwing an exception in your browser please check console what actual error it throws?

Comment: @Curiousdev I think It says **ErrorException in PostController.php line 66:
Trying to get property of non-object**. Do you need me add PostController? function?

Comment: ohhh but i can't assume what's on **Line 66** debug and check what's going wrong?

Comment: @Curiousdev I wrote the function I use in PostController in case it helps. I have been working on this for about 4 days, so whatever you need I will provide :D

Comment: `if (Auth::user() != $post->user) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
` comment this condition for a while and than check is it working ?

Comment: No it doesn't seem to change anything. I tried that code before for one element update and it worked properly, I dont believe it is something related with that :/ By the way I tried what you said.

Comment: @Curiousdev Can you please rate it up If you can't  solve? That so more people will be interestedin? -_-

Comment: ohhh i have done that :)

Comment: Can you post the version in which it worked?

Comment: @motanelu Yeap added it belove the question

Comment: In the Javascript, can you make sure that `postId` is always set correctly? Basically what happens is that you don't find the `$post` object and when you're trying to call `$post->user` it fails.

Comment: @motanelu Whow I actually just realised that too.... I'm working on it...

Comment: I use this line to access to postId `postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];` But apparently I'm accesing to a wrong node

Comment: So, what's your status? Any luck?

Comment: Nah, I'm trying to solve it by rewriting the code and checking everything in console

Comment: @motanelu I'm trying to pick the post id from a data but I fail targeting it, can you help me with that if I create a new question and write my html in it plus the way I was trying to acces the id?

Comment: I can surely try! But you can update this question, there's no need to create a new one.

Comment: @motanelu I updated the question as you recommended, appreciate  all the help you did so far, If you figure out how I should target the `data-postid="{{ $post->id }}"`  than write it as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: The article is the forth parent of any anchor, add 2 times more `.parentNode` to reach it.

Comment: @skobaljic Now we are talking. it works :D . Can you write that as an answer so I accept it and maybe it will as well be helpfull to somebody else. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you catch the click event on your anchor(s), the container article is the 4th parent element of it. To reach it (and its data), you need to add `.parentNode` two more times:

```
postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
```

In case your are working with jQuery, than best you could do is to call its [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find the nearest article this way (assuming you are watching the anchor click event):

```
postId = $(this).closest('article').data('postid');
```

That method does following (what we need indeed):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: one last thing I would like to ask, can I target the dataset with jquery? cuz I believe I might change the html later on and that is probably gonna cause problems and I will have troubles pointing the problem out

Comment: With jQuery you would never had such trouble, please check the updated answer :)

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot, I knew I have something like that to pick with jquery, cuz I previously used jquery to target things and they never run into such problems. In jquery website I found few examples but couldn't implement it into my code. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you would be accepting of including a polyfill in your project, but by using the `.closest` method you will be able to solve this very easily. (The polyfill isn't 100% necessary, but browser support isn't perfect yet, so it depends on your targeted browser support)

[Polyfill here](https://github.com/jonathantneal/closest)

Now with the `.closest` method available, the following is possible:

```
var postId = event.target.closest('article.post').dataset['postid'];
```

Comment: That worked well on chrome and mozilla properly but for some reason the modal is not even popping up in opera and edge, I didn't even link that file up.

Comment: @Nikonah Opera and Edge are the two browsers that are known to lack support for `closest`, that is the reasoning behind needing the polyfill.